# Slicing an iterable - Function not working(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have been posed the following question:

> Make a new function named first_and_last_4. It'll accept a single iterable but, this time, it'll return the first four and last four items as a single value.

Here is my code:

```
def first_and_last_4(x):
    first_4 = x[:4]
    last_4 = x[-4:]
    return (first_4.extend(last_4))
```

I have also tried to simplify this:

```
def first_and_last_4(x):
    return x[:4] + x[-4:]
```

**Error**:

> Bummer: Couldn't find `first_4`

Can you help?

Comment: What is your input to the function? And you should fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
def first_and_last_4(x):
    return x[:4]+x[-4:] #you had indentation problem here
```

Comment: Will try this! Thanks

Comment: what's your traceback?

Comment: Bummer: Couldn't find first_4

Comment: Please give your full code,why do you need first_4 here?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. An iterable need not be a `list`, so list slicing should not be assumed as an acceptable solution. To extract the elements you require, you can create an iterator via built-in `iter`:

- For the first `n` elements, you can use a list comprehension over `range(n)`.
- For the last `n` elements, you can use `collections.deque` and set `maxlen=n`.

Here's an example:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque

def first_and_last_n(x, n=4):
    iter_x = iter(x)
    first_n = [next(iter_x) for _ in range(n)]
    last_n = list(deque(iter_x, maxlen=n))
    return first_n + last_n

res = first_and_last_n(range(10))

print(res)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```